# how to swap all pair of elements in deeply nested vector in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

say I have something like

```
[[[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]]] [[[7 8] [9 10]]] [[[2 4]]]]
```

I want to swap the inner most pairs to make it

```
[[[[2 1] [4 3] [6 5]]] [[[8 7] [10 9]]] [[[4 2]]]]
```

Suppose I don't know the depth before I got the data, and all pairs are at the same depth level.

What is an idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: How did you end up with this problem?  When you say "innermost" it appears you mean all of them in this case.  Maybe more test cases would help?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clojure.walk` will do the job:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as walk])

(defn pair? [s]
  (and (vector? s)
       (every? (complement vector?) s)
       (= (count s) 2)))

(defn swap-pairs [s]
  (walk/prewalk #(if (pair? %)
                   (vec (reverse %))
                   %)
                s))
```

You may come up with different `pair?` predicate that better fits your domain.